# How do I iterate a loop over 300 data points over list of dataframe indices in python?

Tags: python, loops, iteration, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I have over 12,000 second data points and have created a loop thats not so great in looking at 300 second intervals, and need to use indices in my loop instead; how can i do this so that i can pull out information about the first 300s interval, and the second interval later when i need it; and how can i fix my existing code to do so ?

```
init_list = [] # initial values for chunks 
median_list = [] # list of median values for 300 s intervals 
holding_list = [] # hold values up till what you tell it to
pos_count = 0 # 0 = position 1 for python
for i in range(len(flux_maxij)): 
    holding_list.append(flux_maxij[i]) # append means add on to 
    if pos_count == 0: # '==' means IF it is this value
        init_list.append(i) 
    if pos_count == 299: # 299 = 300 which is the 'end' of the range 
        holding_list.sort() #make it pretty 
        median_list.append(holding_list[149]) # half of 300 is 150,                149 for python
        holding_list = [] 
        pos_count = -1 # -1+1 = o, position 1 when it loops back 

    pos_count += 1

x = np.array([init_list]) # makes arrays for x and y to graph it 
y = np.array([median_list])

plt.plot(x,y, 's')
```

Comment: Can you show us the structure of flux_maxij?

Comment: As a new user, please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Concerning your question, you will have to be much more specific with your problem description. Also, you should extract a [mcve] from your code before even posting here, it assures a certain question quality.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you can access indices in `flux_maxij`. So presumably you can access slices as well?

You can access the first 300 items with

```
flux_maxij[0:300]
# OR
start = 0
flux_maxij[start:start+300]
```

And `init_list` seems to contain [0, 300, 600, ...]

```
init_list = list(range(0, len(flux_maxij), 300))  # range from 0 to the total length, jumping 300 each time
median_list = []
for i in init_list:
    holding = sorted(flux_maxij[i:i+300])  # get the next bit of the list and sort it
    median_list.append(holding[149])  # append the median

x = np.array([init_list])
y = np.array([median_list])

plt.plot(x, y, 's')
```

Does that work? It's hard to understand without knowing what `flux_maxij` is.

Comment: Sorry! I think its almost there i'm trying to fix "IndexError: list index out of range" but flux_maxij is data from 1 night of observing a black hole's flux and how it changed !

Comment: actually, i figured out how to graph the fluxes! But im still using probably an inefficient way for it to happen; i just dont understand how to be pulling the 300s intervals from the data file as i need them; like i have the 1st interval graphed now, but will i always have to change the code as needed to print the rest?

Comment: ^ using the indices

Answer (score 0):

Why not just divide your list into 300 equal size segments with:

```
interval = 300
divided_list = [flux_maxij[i:i+interval] for i in range(0, len(flux_maxij), interval)]
```

you can see how range takes three arguments: `range(init_value, end_value, step_size)`
Then print (or store) the desired values for each interval:

```
x = np.array(range(0, len(flux_maxij), interval))
y = np.array([np.median(j) for j in divided_list])
plt.plot(x, y, 's')
```

The one-liner then becomes:

```
plt.plot(np.array(range(0, len(flux_maxij), interval)), 
         np.array([np.median(j) for j in [flux_maxij[i:i+interval] for i in range(0, len(flux_maxij), interval)]]),
         's')
```

Comment: When im trying this out the x values are 55000 to 90000 which shouldn't be possible since i only have 12000 data points; is there any key things i might have forgot to manipulate from the code you posted? Sorry, im new to coding ):

Comment: Hmm...I think I didn't read your question fully the first time around ;). Maybe you need something like `x = np.array(range(0, len(flux_maxij), interval)`. this way x looks like `[0, 300, 600, 900, ...]`. Let me know if that fixed it and I'll make the edit above.

Comment: for some reason the y is throwing an error for 'invalid syntax' !

Comment: actually, i figured out how to graph the fluxes! But im still using probably an inefficient way for it to happen; i just dont understand how to be pulling the 300s intervals from the data file as i need them; like i have the 1st interval graphed now, but will i always have to change the code as needed to print the rest?

Comment: ^ using the indices

Comment: y shouldn't throw any errors in python2 or python3. Check the line before and make sure all your parentheses and brackets are closed. if you copied and pasted x from my comment, you'll be missing a paren :P oops!